# Parse.com. Execute backend code before response

Tags: parse-platform

I need to know the relative position of an object in a list. Lets say I need to know the position of a certain wine of all wines added to the database, based in the votes received by users. The app should be able to receive the ranking position as an object property when retrieving a "wine" class object.

This should be easy to do in the backend side but I've seen Cloud Code and it seems it only is able to execute code before or after saving or deleting, not before reading and giving response.

Any way to do this task?. Any workaround?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to write a Cloud function to perform this calculation for a particular wine.

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions

This would be a function you would call manually. You would have to provide the "wine" object or objectId as a parameter and then get have your cloud function return the value you need. Keep in mind there are limitations on cloud functions. Read the documentation about time limits. You also don't want to make too many API calls every time you run this. It sounds like your computation could be fairly heavy if your dataset is large and you aren't caching at least some of the information.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I forgot you can return a value when executing an afterSave function.